# How to make "Edit Links" visible again

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation, edit-links

As part of our Sharepoint rebranding project, the 3rd party which was doing our template changes, made the edit link option invisible . Now as the site collection admin I am wondering how am I going to simply edit the top navigation links. I tried created a subsite which is not inheriting permission from the parent site but it the same.
I know this script might been used to hide the edit link , but is there any way to change it ( at least for a subsite to be able to see the option? )

```
< style>
  .ms-displayInlineBlock{
     display: none;
  }
< /style>
```

Thank you!

Aysan

Answer (score 1):

It seems likely that the problem you are encountering is caused by your site being a publishing site.  Once you enable the publishing feature, the method for editing the Quick Launch changes.  You probably don't want to disable this feature because it will change other behaviors as well. Here's how to edit the links on either:

- On non-publishing sites, you can modify the Quick Launch via `Edit Links` or `Site Settings -> Look and Feel -> Quick Launch`
- On publishing sites, it is `Settings -> Look and Feel -> Navigation` (there is no shortcut to it like `Edit Links` on non-publishing sites)

The interface is a bit different for publishing sites too, because you modify both the Top Link Bar and the Quick Launch on the same page.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I can`t find an option to edit the quick links in Navigation setting (under site setting) I kind of found a workaround .

Answer (score 1):

The workaround I found was to create a subsite with unique permission and different site template from the parent site, then I was able to see the "edit link" option again